# JS: inline date substring…how to prevent space before?

Tags: javascript, html

Given:

```html
<p id="copyright">
&copy;&nbsp;&apos;
<script>
document.getElementById('copyright').appendChild(document.createTextNode(new Date().getFullYear().toString().substr(-2)))
</script>
Company Name
</p>
```

How does one prevent the space between the ' and the two digit year, i.e.,
© ' 24 Company Name?

Comment: Start the `<script>` tag on the same line as the copyright symbol instead of on a new line. Also this is a pretty hack way of doing things.

Comment: just create a span in the right place

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very simple, just remove the whitespace you put there (remember that the newline counts as whitespace here):

```html
<p id="copyright">
&copy;&nbsp;&apos;<script>
document.getElementById('copyright').appendChild(document.createTextNode(new Date().getFullYear().toString().substr(-2)))
</script>
Company Name
</p>
```

Indeed hacky though. Here is another approach:

```js
const copyrightYear = new Date().getFullYear().toString().substr(-2)
document.querySelector('#copyright-year').textContent = copyrightYear
```

```html
<p id="copyright">
  &copy;&nbsp;&apos;<span id="copyright-year"></span>
  Company Name
</p>
```

Note that here, too, there must not be any whitespace between `&apos;` and `<span id="copyright-year"></span>`.

Answer (score 0):

There is hidden whitespace on the left of the script tag. You can fix it like this:

```html
<p id="copyright">
&copy;&nbsp;&apos;<script>
document.getElementById('copyright').appendChild(document.createTextNode(new Date().getFullYear().toString().substr(-2)))
</script>
Company Name
</p>
```

Comment: Thanks. VS Code kept throwing a line break in!